# ¿Se puede mejorar este código en C?

Tags: c

```
/*
    Listas doblemente enlazadas
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

//Estructura del nodo
typedef struct nodo
{
    int dato;
    struct nodo *siguiente;
    struct nodo *anterior;
} NODO;


NODO *CrearNodo(int dato);
int InsertarInicio(NODO **cabeza, int dato);
int InsertarFinal(NODO **cabeza, int dato);
void ImprimirLista(NODO *cabeza);
int EliminarNodo(NODO **cabeza, int dato);


int main()
{
    int c;
    int eli;
    int x,y,num,i=0,j=0,k=0;
    NODO *cabeza = NULL;
    printf("----------------LISTA DOBLEMENTE ENLAZADA----------------\n");
    printf("Ingrese cuantos elementos desea insertar a la lista:  \n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("\n\n");
    while(i<num){
    printf("Ingrese un numero para la lista: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf(" ¿Desea colocarlo al incio de la lista o al final de la lista? \n");
    printf("1.INICIO \n2.FINAL \n");  
    printf("Ingrese 1 o 2: ");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("\n");
    while(y!=1 && y!=2){
    printf("Caracter no permitido \n");
    printf("Ingrese 1 o 2: ");
    scanf("%d",&y);printf("\n");
    }if(y==1){
    InsertarInicio(&cabeza, x);
    }    
    else{InsertarFinal(&cabeza, x);}
    i++;                  
    }
    printf("--------IMPRIMIENDO LISTA--------\n\n");
    printf("cargando");
    Sleep(1000);
    while(j<6){
    printf(".");
    Sleep(1000);
    j++;
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
    ImprimirLista(cabeza);  
    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf(" ¿Desea eliminar algun elemento de la lista? \nIngrese\n 1.)SI o 2.)NO (escriba los numeros):  ");  
    scanf("%d",&c);
    printf("\n\n");
    while(c!=1 && c!=2){
        printf("Caracter no permitido \n");
        printf("Ingrese si o no: ");
        scanf("%d",&c);
        printf("\n\n");
        }
        Sleep(1000);
        if(c==1){
        printf("Ingrese el elemento que desea eliminar:  ");
        scanf("%d",&eli);
        EliminarNodo(&cabeza,eli);
        Sleep(1000);
        Sleep(1000);
        printf("\n");
        printf("--------IMPRIMIENDO NUEVA LISTA--------\n\n");
        printf("cargando");
        Sleep(1000);
        while(k<6){
        printf(".");
        Sleep(1000);
        k++;
        }
        printf("\n\n");
        ImprimirLista(cabeza);
        printf("\n\n");
        }else{}      
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//Función para eliminar un nodo de la lista
int EliminarNodo(NODO **cabeza, int dato)
{
    NODO *actual = *cabeza, *ant = NULL, *sig = NULL;

    while(actual != NULL)
    {
        if(actual->dato == dato)
        {
            if( actual == *cabeza)
            {
                *cabeza = actual->siguiente;
                if( actual->siguiente != NULL)
                    actual->siguiente->anterior = NULL;
            }
            else if( actual->siguiente == NULL)
            {
                ant = actual->anterior;
                actual->anterior = NULL;
                ant->siguiente = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                ant = actual->anterior;
                actual->anterior = NULL;
                sig = actual->siguiente;
                actual->siguiente = NULL;
                ant->siguiente = sig;
                sig->anterior = ant;
            }
            free(actual);
            return 1;
        }
        actual = actual->siguiente;
    }
    return 0;
}

//Función para insertar al final de la lista
int InsertarFinal(NODO **cabeza, int dato)
{
    NODO *nuevo = NULL, *nAux = *cabeza;

    nuevo = CrearNodo(dato);
    if (nuevo != NULL)
    {
        while(nAux->siguiente != NULL){ nAux = nAux->siguiente;}
        nuevo->anterior = nAux;
        nAux->siguiente = nuevo;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

//Función para imprimir la lista
void ImprimirLista(NODO *cabeza)
{
    NODO *nAux = cabeza;

    while(nAux != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", nAux->dato);
        nAux = nAux->siguiente;
    }
}

//Función para insertar al inicio de la lista
int InsertarInicio(NODO **cabeza, int dato)
{
    NODO *nuevo = NULL;

    nuevo = CrearNodo(dato);
    if (nuevo != NULL)
    {
        nuevo->siguiente = *cabeza;
        nuevo->anterior = NULL;
        if( *cabeza != NULL)
            (*cabeza)->anterior = nuevo;
        *cabeza = nuevo;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

//Función para crear un nuevo nodo
NODO *CrearNodo(int dato)
{
    NODO* nuevo = NULL;

    nuevo = (NODO*)malloc(sizeof(NODO));
    if( nuevo != NULL)
    {
        nuevo->dato = dato;
        nuevo->siguiente = NULL;
        nuevo->anterior = NULL;
    }
    return nuevo;
}
```

Comment: Removida etiqueta C++ y arreglado el título, revertir en caso erróneo.

Comment: Por lo que veo en el comentario a la respuesta de @AlvaroAraujo, **el código no es tuyo**. ¿ Estas pidiendo ayuda para una tarea escolar, en la que no has hecho **nada**, y te has limitado a copiar el código de otro ???? -1. Y voto para cerrarla.

Comment: El código es mío, y no es para una tarea escolar. Es malo preguntar?
Trato de mejorar como programador, estoy iniciando en este mundo y no es malo siempre una recomendación, dado que no puedo entender tanto como usted

Comment: Si el código fuera tuyo, sabrías **perfectamente** como hacer la modificación que te indican, puesto que es mucho mas simple que el código que ya *tienes hecho*. Y, o es para una tarea, o para algún cursillo o similar. Eso salta a la vista. Y, para tareas escolares, se decidió **por consenso de la comunidad**, **que es necesario mostrar el código que ya tengas realizado**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pienso que deberías crear otra estructura donde guardes la información de la lista completa, lo básico que podrías guardar es: un puntero al inicio de la lista y otro puntero al final de la lista, también podrías guardar la cardinalidad (numero de elementos en la lista). La estructura sería algo como esto:

```
typedef struct lista {
   NODO *inicio;
   NODO *fin;
   int cardinalidad;
}LISTA;
```

Todo esto con el fin de aplicar mejoras de rendimiento.

- Al tener un puntero al inicio de la lista y otro al final puedes realizar las inserciones al principio o al final de la lista en O(1), actualmente InsertarFinal() tiene un tiempo de O(n) ya que tienes que recorrer toda la lista para llegar al final de la misma.
- Una de las virtudes de las listas doblemente enlazadas es que puedes recorrerlas en dos sentidos; entonces para la función de eliminar, en un mismo ciclo de repetición puedes moverte en los dos sentidos ya que tienes un puntero en el inicio y otro al final, empiezas a recorrer del inicio al fin y viceversa, el tiempo de búsqueda del elemento a eliminar se te reducirá a la mitad.

A grandes rasgos creo que con estas mejoras que acabo de mencionarte podrías aumentar el rendimiento considerablemente, específicamente en la eliminación o búsqueda y en la inserción al final de la lista.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tomaré en referencia esto y mejoraré la eficiencia de mi código !

Comment: Si esta respuesta te sirvió, por favor marcala como aceptada